# Python не видит переменную

Tags: python, psycopg2

Python не видит переменную connection, хотя я ее прописываю в блоке try. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело.

```
import psycopg2
from file2 import host, user, password, db_name

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT version();')
        print(f'Server version: {cursor.fetchone()}')
except Exception as ex:
    print('[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL', ex)
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
        print('[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')
```

Comment: как вы поняли, что ёё не видит `python`

Comment: Выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'connection' is not defined

Comment: Если при вызове `psycopg2.connect()` вылетит исключение, то в connection ничего не будет записано, в итоге получите ошибку NameError в finally. Инициализируйте connection до блока try: `connection = None`.

Comment: можно `finally` заменить на `else`.

Comment: Спасибо всем, работает!